# Choosing allocated letters, menu type

Tags: python, eclipse

I am new to programming, so please excuse my lack of knowledge. I am trying to write a code using python to choose a specific letter to get to a certain menu.

```
For example:
print("Menu")
print("Food")
print("Calculate)
```

I then want to type either m, f or c and then for that to take me to the specific choice. Would I go about it in a secret letter kind of style.. using while letter != ... print "invalid"? I'm not sure if I am explaining this well at all.

Please help!

Comment: This question should be covered in about every tutorial on Python. Please do your homework first before asking questions here.

Comment: I did, thank you. I actually spent hours trying to figure it out. Comes faster to some than others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `in` keyword to check if a character (or substring) is inside another. Here we are using `not in` to check if `choice` is not inside `"mfc"`.

To get an input (as string), you can use `raw_input()`. And finally a simple `if-elif-else` structure to check which option was chosen:

```
print("Menu")
print("Food")
print("Calculate")

choice = raw_input("Enter choice: ")

while choice not in "mfc":
    choice = raw_input("Invalid. Enter choice: ")

if choice == 'm':
    # ...
elif choice == 'f':
    # ...
else:
    # ...
```